# Spring Boot Devtools not working using Gradle

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-devtools

I have created a simple Spring Boot app using IntelliJ that use Spring Boot Devtools as dependency and Gradle as build automation with option: `Use default gradle wrapper`. However, the Devtools seems not working. When I change my html file, the page does not updated even though I refresh it several times. I use [Spring Boot Devtools docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) as reference.

My `application.properties` is empty

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**Interesting fact**:
I have tried in several Spring Boot versions (from `1.5.12.RELEASE` until `2.1.0.RELEASE`), but the result is still the same.

**But** when I switch from Gradle to Maven, the Devtools surprisingly worked!

Any clue anyone? I want to use Gradle, not Maven.

Additional information:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- IDE: IntelliJ 2018.2
- Java: `openjdk 11 2018-09-25`
- Gradle version: 4.8.1
- Gradle JVM: `java version 1.8.0__151`
- Gradle run method: `./gradlew bootRun`
- Maven version: 3.5.2
- Maven run method: `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: Could you please add errors logs?

Comment: Here is the [log](https://pastebin.com/w4TPnwFV) . Actually, there is no error message appeared (because I use the default log level, which is `INFO`), but if needed, I can provide the debug message log.

Comment: Seems all is OK, could you please try with gradle only? if you don't have one, install and put gradle bootRun

Comment: I installed Gradle 4.8.1 (same as the Gradle wrapper) and run `gradle bootRun` but still not working.

Actually in my description above, I run Gradle and Maven separately, not together, just want to know if I use Maven, it will work or not.